# Is there a way in dotnet core to deserialize an object field into a string directly in the DTO?

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller, model-binding

My DTO has a field that is a JSON. I would like to receive it as a string instead.

The controller receives a body like so: `public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] MyDto dto)`

The DTO looks like this:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
}
```

This does not work, as it won't automatically deserialize the "Json" object into a string. I need to use another type, like JObject or Dynamic, then transfer it in an Entity which has this field as a string.

I would like to directly transform the JObject I receive into a string, so my DTO could still use a string. Is there a way to specify a binding or deserialization method to this specific field, so it does a `.ToString()` before?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have the payload consist of an actual string instead of an object then, since JavaScript's JSON serialization is faster anyways?

Comment: Could you provide an ajax call how you send data?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of Json to dynamic.

```
  public class MyDto
  {
      public string Field1 { get; set; }
      public dynamic Json { get; set; } 
  }
```

when you deserialize, it will convert it to a dynamic object, not a string.

Ideally, you want to use another object that classifies what the json object is supposed to be

```
  public class MyJsonObject
  {
    public string Field1OfJson {get;set;}
    public string Field2OfJson {get;set;}
  }

  // Then use that as the type
  public class MyDto
  {
      public string Field1 { get; set; }
      public MyJsonObject Json { get; set; } 
  }
```

This way you can access the data under Json easily.

Comment: What I'm trying to find is a way to have a DTO use a string type, and pre-process the convertion with a binding of some sort, maybe with an attribute? I do not know how I could do that. Right now I'm using an object type (similar to dynamic), but this means I have to convert it in my mappings to Entities and add special IEquals implementations to compare object with string and vise versa (or dynamic with string)